# For loop does not throw errorlevel of 1 when folder is empty

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, errorlevel

I have the following line in a batch script

```
for %%a in (*.rmt) do (findstr /C:"        model='" %%a)>tmp.par
```

When I run this on an empty folder, the errorlevel is still 0.

However, if I replace *.rmt with a filename, say x.rmt, which doesnt exist in the folder either, the errorlevel becomes 1.

Ideally, if there are no RMT files in the folder, shouldnt the errorlevel!=0?

I require this For loop to work on *.rmt, as there might be 0 to multiple RMT files in a folder. Please help.

Thanks.

Note: If the string "        model='" exists in one RMT file, it will compulsorily be present in all the other RMT files(if any) in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `findstr` is never executed if there are no matches to the `*.rmt`, hence the `errorlevel` remains unchanged.

When you use `x.rmt`, `FOR` changes behaviour - it's no longer looking for a filename matching, it's looking at a particular string - which may or may not be a filename, which may or may not exist.

You could deliberately set `errorlevel` before the `for`

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO y|FIND "x">nul
for %%a in (*.rmt) do (findstr /C:"        model='" %%a)
ECHO errorlevel=%errorlevel%
GOTO :EOF
```

which will return `errorlevel` 1 unless the match is found.

Comment: Thanks!! Simple workaround by deliberately setting the errorlevel to 1!

Comment: Just one question..Could you please explain how the errorlevel is getting set as 1? What do these 2 lines do?      SETLOCAL     ECHO y|FIND "x">nul

Comment: The `SETLOCAL` is not relevant. It simply ensures that the environment remains unchanged when the batch ends - useful when one run of a batch may leave variables set and affect further batches. The `ECHO` line is one of many ways to set `errorlevel` non-zero. It sends `y` as input to the `find` utility, which is attempting to find the string "`x`". `FIND` will set `errorlevel` to `0` if it finds the string, `1` otherwise. The `>nul` redirects any output to the `nul` device, simply toosing it away so that nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: A more efficient way to set ERRORLEVEL to 1 is `(call)`, without a space. A good way to set ERRORLEVEL to 0 is `(call )`, with a space. Presetting the ERRORLEVEL only works because all .RMT files contain the search string, or none of them do. At first I missed the significance of that fact in the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b "path_to_dir\*.rmt"') do (
   :: echo Folder is NON empty
   findstr /C:"model='" %%i >> C:\testlog.log
   goto :EOF
)
```

Comment: You should add `"delims="` to handle files with space in name, or `"eol=: delims="` to protect against unlikely event of file name beginning with `;`

Answer (score 0):

No, the FOR command never sets the ERRORLEVEL <> 0 if there are no iterations.

Yes, the following command reports ERRORLEVEL=1:

```
for %%a in (notExists.rmt) do (findstr /C:"        model='" %%a)>tmp.par
```

But that is because the simple FOR simply lists the string(s) within the IN() clause if they do not contain wildcards. It doesn't bother checking to see if the file exists. So your FINDSTR command is actually raising the error because it cannot find the file, not the FOR statement.

Your command is flawed in that each iteration overwrites the previous tmp.par. That can be easily fixed by adding an extra level of parentheses. This also will create an empty tmp.par if no files were found or if none of the files contained the search string. The ERRORLEVEL cannot be relied upon because its value will not have been set if no files were found, or it may be 0 or 1 depending on if the last file contained the search string.

```
(for %%a in (*.rmt) do (findstr /C:"        model='" %%a))>tmp.par
```

If you don't mind having a `filename:` prefix on each line of output, then you can simplify your code to:

```
findstr /C:"        model='" *.rmt >tmp.par 2>nul
```

This also will create an empty tmp.par file if no files were found, or if none of the files contain the search string. But now the ERRORLEVEL will be reliable. The ERRORLEVEL is 1 if no files are found or if no files contain the search string. Otherwise the ERRORLEVEL will be 0.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation! Very helpful!